# How to affect the position of equation labels when using "aligned" environments inside an "align" environment

Tags: amsmath, labels, tag

```
\begin{align}\label{abc}
    &f(x,y,z) = \begin{aligned}[t]
        & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        & + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        & - aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
    \end{aligned}\\\label{abcd}
    &g(x,y,z,w) = \begin{aligned}[t]
        & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        & + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
        & - aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\eqref{abc} \eqref{abcd}
```

[image: img]

I want to change the position of (15) and (16) to where I want.

Is there any options like [t], [c], [b]?

The options [t] that I think imply that (15) is located the first line like the above figure.

The options [c] that I think imply that (15) is located the second line like the following figure.

[image]

The options [b] that I think imply that (15) is located the third line like the following figure.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate Where I want here?

Comment: I've just added figures that I want. The figures are not from the LaTex. They are from the mspaint program. (I drew it.)

Comment: the positioning options for `aligned` are meant to position the aligned block itself relative to what it follows, not the position of the label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To influence the vertical position of the equation label associated with a given `aligned` environment, you mainly need to reorganize some of the material.

For instance, in order to achieve top-alignment of the equation number, don't write

```
\label{abc}
&f(x,y,z) = \begin{aligned}[t]
    & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    & + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    & - aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
\end{aligned}\\
```

Instead, you need to write

```
&\begin{aligned}[t] \label{abc}
f(x,y,z)   &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
              &\quad+ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
              &\quad- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 
\end{aligned}\\
```

The single most important change is the placement of `\begin{aligned}[t]`: instead of coming *after* `f(x,y,z)`, it has to come before it.

By the way, the only real placement options are `[t]` and `[b]` (for top and bottom); any other letter, including (but not limited to) `[c]`, is ignored, resulting in the default placement, which is centered.

---

Here's a full MWE (minimum working example) which places the equation labels on the bottom rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{14} % just for this example

\begin{align}
    &\begin{aligned}[b] \label{abc}
       f(x,y,z)   &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
                  &\quad+ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
                  &\quad- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, 
    \end{aligned}\\[1ex] % some extra whitespace, for "visual grouping"
    &\begin{aligned}[b] \label{abcd}
       g(x,y,z,w) &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
                  &\quad + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
                  &\quad - aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\eqref{abc}, \eqref{abcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have pondered more!.. I just thought that there exist some options or new environments that I do not know yet. However, what I want can be done with only align and aligned environments. Very thank you~

Answer (score 4):

It's far more convenient to use `align` as-is with appropriately placed `\nonumber` (or `\notag`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x,y,z) 
      &=  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \nonumber \\
      &\qquad {}+ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \nonumber \\
      &\qquad {}- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, \label{eqn:abc} \\
  g(x,y,z,w)
      &=  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \nonumber \\
      &\qquad {}+ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \nonumber \\
      &\qquad {}- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, \label{eqn:abcd}
\end{align}
See equations~\eqref{eqn:abc} and~\eqref{eqn:abcd}.

\end{document}
```

While the alignment above is different from what you've supplied, that can be changed.